# Why would you pass a class as a lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, sqlalchemy, graphql

I constructed my first GraphQL API from online examples and tutorials, but like to know why certain things are done in Python.

A snippet of a class I don't understand:

```
class UpdateRegion(graphene.Mutation):
    """Update a region."""
    region = graphene.Field(lambda: Region, description="Region updated by this mutation.")
...
```

The Region class:

```
class Region(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
   class Meta:
       model = RegionModel
       interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

Why are they passing in the `Region` class as a lambda function?
To me `lambda: Region` is the same as `f():return Region`

Comment: because `lambda` definition is shorter then similar function definition

Comment: If the definition of that `Field` parameter is that it should be **a `Callable`** which returns an object/constructor/something else specifically, that's a natural way to do it.

Comment: How can I easily spot that it has to be a callable? Because the documentation isn't clear

Comment: Well, the documentation should be clearer. If it isn't, you can try digging into the code itself.

Comment: Note: when using the Field constructor directly, pass the type and not an instance.
Types mounted in a Field act as Arguments.

That's the only hint they give in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To me `lambda: Region` is the same as `f():return Region`

For starters, `f():return Region` isn't valid syntax. This can, of course, be fixed:

```
def f():
  return Region

region = graphene.Field(f, ...)
```

This will work and is roughly equivalent to `region = graphene.Field(lambda: Region, ...)`. The latter is shorter and arguably clearer.

Comment: How is passing `Field(lambda: Region)` different than `Field(Region)`?

Comment: @GPhilo It is one level deeper. The lambda object `lambda: Region` must be called to get `Region`, then again to get a `Region` instance. OTOH, `Region` itself must only be called once to get a `Region` instance.

Comment: I see! Thanks, I missed that detail